# Composite or single unique index constraint?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large table with approx 30 columns. I want to use 10 of them to create a unique constraint.

As my table is 24h temporary data, I could as well just concatenate the 10 column values into an additional column, and only have 1 single unique column at the end.

My goal is to `LOAD DATA INFILE` into a temp table, then update the main table every 24h. During that `SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE <fields>` I need the unique constraint.

Question: with this perspektive, is there any advantage of creating a unique constraint on multiple columns instead of only one?

Comment: Depends on what datatype the columns are. For performance I would suggest using only 1 column instead.

Comment: The columns are mainly `varchar`s.

Answer (score 2):

There's no significant difference between a multi-column unique constraint and a single-column unique constraint. I would not recommend concatenating the columns together just for that, if you ever need to run a query that references one of the columns individually. You'll be doomed to run SUBSTR() functions forever, and make your queries more complex unnecessarily.

Either way, you should know that there's a byte limit on indexes. If you're trying to make a unique key (or even a non-unique key) over 10 varchar columns, they better be short.

Answer (score 1):

As per  [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144/when-should-i-use-a-unique-constraint-instead-of-a-unique-index/55139), using index is better suited as your process involves search and update. It must be noted that, creating individual unique constraints for each required column is different than creating single unique constraint for all the required columns. The latter looks for a unique combination of all the required columns while the former looks for uniqueness for that single column.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Bill's answer, there is one major disadvantage to concatenating the columns.  A composite index can be used for other queries.

So, a unique index on `(a, b, c, d, e)` can be used for queries such as:

```
where a = @a

where a = @a and b = @b and c between @c1 and @c2
```

and so on.

If you are going to have an index, you might as well have it be as useful as possible.